# Application server certificate is not working after importing

Tags: server, certificate

I have created certificate request from IIS for my application server and prepared .cer file with the help of CA authority. While i am using complete certificate steps from IIS ,its not giving any error, but when i am trying to bind the `https://` certificate disappears from IIS -> Server certificates. i am installing webhosting certificate into windows based server.

Comment: When you run `certlm.msc` do you see the certificate under `My` or `Web Hosting`? Does the icon of the certificate indicate you have the private key?

Comment: did you create the CSR (certificate signing request) on the same server you're trying to install the certificate on ?